# Java - Creating new object in method VS declaring it as class member

Tags: java, performance, memory, javafx, jvm

Assume we have a method which removes all items from a `ListView` and then adds a `Label` with a text specified by user: (*Label is being used as an example, it could by any Object*)

Example A keeps smaller variable scope but creates a new Object on each method call:

```
public void populateListView() {
   listView.getItems().clear();
   Label label = new Label("some string from user");
   listView.getItems().add(label);
}
```

Example B has wider variable scope but the Object is created only once on class load. Also, instead of creating a new `Label`, the same `Label` reference is being used.

```
public class MyClass{
    private Label label = new Label();

    public void populateListView() {
        listView.getItems().clear();
        label.setText("some string from user");
        listView.getItems().add(label);
    }
}
```

We can see that in Example A, the very first line clears all object references of `listView`.

Does this mean that, on a new method call, the `Label` created in the previous method call will be garbage collected (and how fast)?

In other words, considering we call each method multiple times, will example B more efficient in terms of memory allocation? If yes, considering the '*always keeping the smallest scope*' which example should be chosen over and why?

Comment: 1.- yes, it will be GCed at some point. 2.- yes

Comment: *"How fast?"* this depends on a lot of factors. There are different strategied for the garbage collector to choose and it also depends on the available/used memory...

Comment: I'd use the first method, just to keep readability at its best. Unless you have thousands of Labels, I'm not sure that this kind of optimization is worthwile

Comment: JavaFX is a façade around an extended Webkit engine. These objects are entirely irrelevant to the performance of your application. The expensive part is the DOM tree and what the engine does with on the non-Java side. A label is a label, whether you describe it with a new object or an existing.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your input. Your comment seems quite interesting, are there are articles/resources where I could read more about your concept?

Comment: Well, it tries hard to abstract away the implementation details, but you see all the signs, like the limited modification abilities after starting to display a scene, all the typical (for Java) ways of customization not working, but instead, having to style everything with CSS only. In theory, the API allows other backend implementations, but the fundamental property would stay the same; the hard work is not done by the frontend classes you see…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premature optimization should be avoided as it decreases the code quality.
Besides if you have a memory issue, it is very few probably that it be the main cause as a `Label` is not a heavy object (the object itself, not its rendering) and you don't create thousands of it in the method.
So let the Garbage collector does its job and keep a clear code by reducing the scope of variables to the strict required (example A).

If later you have a memory issue at runtime, profile your application (with JVisualVM for example) to spot the culprit (that will very probably not be this one).

Comment: Thank you for your input. To conclude, I should always follow Example A's approach, unless the Object is huge or there is very limited available memory?

Comment: Broadly yes. Not that I would take care if the Object is "huge" not only because I want to spare memory but because allocating/collecting a big Object may take time and so have a cost in term of CPU consumed too.